# ajax is returning 0

Tags: ajax

This is the first time i am trying to fire ajax in WordPress. I know i am making mistake which is not letting my ajax run so please help me to figure it out.

Here is my js code -

[image]

Here is my ajax code -

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to follow these steps to properly call ajax function in WordPress,

1. Register and localize your script, eg.

   ```
   wp_register_script(
         '*handle_name*'
       , *js_file_path*
       , array(
           *dependency_name*
       )
       , true
       , true
   );
   ```

   It will load your script at page footer. Refer to the following link: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_register_script/

   ```
   wp_localize_script(
         '*handle_name*'
       , '*a_unique_name_to_call_this_object*'
       , array(
           'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
           'if_require_any_more_field' => 'necessary_value',
       )
   );
   ```

   It will create a js object with two properties, **ajaxurl** and if_require_any_more_field. Refer the following link: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script
2. Then Enqueue the script `wp_enqueue_script('*handle_name*');`
3. In your javascript/jQuery code

   ```
       var formDate = jQuery('#tpform1').serialize();                      
       var data = {
           action : 'trade_partners',
           form : formData
       }

       $.post(unique_object_name.ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
           alert(response);           
       });
   ```
4. Now time to write your php ajax calling function in `functions.php` file (for best practice)

   ```
   add_action('wp_ajax_trade_partners', 'custom_action');
   add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_trade_partners', 'custom_action');     

   function custom_action() {
       global $wpdb;
       echo "<pre>";
       print_r($wpdb);
   }
   ```

If you use you write your js code within that php file, then you directly jumped into `3rd step`, and within the `script tag` you need to create a variable which have the ajaxurl, ex: `var ajaxurl = "<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ); ?>";` and modify the line where actual ajax function is calling,

```
 $.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
     alert(response);           
 });
```

Comment: Bandhu
Actually my folder structure is different.
I am not firing ajax via functions.php, I do have my another folder which contains files further and one of them file is being is to fire ajax request.

Comment: Do you want see my folder structure, please?
Here is my folder structure - 
[link] https://gyazo.com/3ea064a2b0774123843b553878f6b458

I am using TradePartners folder and here is the its structure -
https://gyazo.com/ca7eb28fabe5df1df42592e3a1b920a1

And here is the js folder file - 
https://gyazo.com/372c090a2d16334b3e835f2b23e34d39

This is the code of js file - 
https://gyazo.com/e57024d9b4c2a8a1d1922083a408b97d

Comment: So above js code sends ajax request -
https://gyazo.com/4c6428da5bf700e15dffe46d7620b59b

But unfortunately i get 0 in return.

And now i send you my php code which is at `trade.partners.ajax.php` which is inside `TradePartners` folder  also - 
https://gyazo.com/6fba8ff371abd1a9b9de414bd3b8b59a

Comment: If you have any doubt then please let me know i will tell you everything about folders and files.

Comment: problem is resolved.
Actually i did not add `trade.partners.ajax.php` file inside functions.php file of the theme. I just added and it is working smoothly now.
Thanks for your support!